# ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} equivalent in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

The title should say it all. I'm looking for an equivalent to `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` in zsh.

*Note:* I keep finding "`$0` is equivalent to `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`" around the Internet, but this seems to be false: `$0` seems to be the name of the executing command. (It's `argv[0]`, which makes sense.) Echoing $0 in my script (`.zshrc`) gives `zsh` for `$0`, which isn't the same as what `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` is. In fact, `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` seems to work in `zsh`, except for inside `.zshrc` files.

*What I'm really doing in my `.zshrc` (that isn't working):*

```
echo ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
source `dirname $0`/common-shell-rc.sh
```

The source fails (`$0` is `zsh`) and the `echo` outputs a blank line.

**Edit:** <strike>apparently, for `$0` to work, I need the option `FUNCTION_ARGZERO` option set. Any way to test if this is set in a script? (so that I can temporarily set it)</strike> It is apparently on unless you set `nofunction_argzero`, and it is on in my shell. Still get nothing for `$0`. (I think b/c I'm not in a function.)

Answer (score 76):

`${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` equivalent in zsh is `${(%):-%N}`, NOT `$0`(as OP said, the latter failed in .zshrc)

Here `%` indicates prompt expansion on the value,
`%N` indicates "The name of the script, sourced file,
or shell function that zsh is currently executing,

whichever was started most recently. If there is none, this is equivalent to the parameter $0."(from `man zshmisc`)

Comment: Great - this should work for the OP, but note that the true `$BASH_SOURCE` equivalent is `%x`, not `%N`, as it refers to the enclosing _file_ even when called inside of _functions_ - in other words: use `${(%):-%x}`

Comment: Hey, reading the documentation, I don't understand why we need the `:-` in here, and why `${(%)%N}` wouldn't work the same (note: I am aware it doesn't work)

Comment: Is there a documentation which other options apart form -%N are available?

Comment: Note: if your zshrc file is a symlink, you can use `readlink` to resolve to the absolute path: `readlink -f ${(%):-%N}`

Comment: PierreBdR: `${(%)%N}` is like `${%N}`, but subject to the (%) flag. `${%N}` would attempt to expand the variable with an empty-string name (which isn't a real thing, but always successfully expands to nothing) and remove a trailing N. Using `${(%):-%N}` attempts to expand that same empty-string variable, and then since that's empty, uses `%N` as a default value... which is then expanded like a prompt because of the (%) flag.

Comment: If you want an even more terse way of finding the absolute path of the directory containing the source code, this will handle that: `${${(%):-%x}:A:h}`

Comment: @PierreBdR Prompt expansion works on the results of the parameter expansion, not the name of the parameter. You could do `foo=%N` followed by `${(%)foo}`, but that's two steps.  `${(%):-%N}` removes the need to define a named parameter by using a null parameter name (which can't have any value) with the `:-` default-value syntax.

Answer (score 70):

**`${(%):-%x}`** is the closest `zsh` equivalent to `bash`'s `$BASH_SOURCE` (and `ksh`'s `${.sh.file}`) - *not* `$0`.

<sup>Tip of the hat to Hui Zheng for providing the crucial pointer and background information in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23259585/45375).</sup>

It returns the (potentially relative) path of the enclosing *script*,

- regardless of whether the script is being *sourced* or not.

  - specifically, it also works inside initialization/profiles files such as `~/.zshrc` (unlike `$0`, which inexplicably returns the *shell*'s path there).
- regardless of whether called from inside a *function* defined in the script or not (unlike `$0`, which returns the *function* name inside a function).

<sup>The only difference to `$BASH_SOURCE` I've found is in the following obscure scenario - which may even be a bug (observed in zsh 5.0.5): inside a function *nested inside another function* in a sourced script, `${(%):-%x}` does *not* return the enclosing script path when that nested function is called (again) *later*, *after* having been sourced (returns either nothing or 'zsh').</sup>

---

**Background information** on `${(%):-%x}`:

- `(%):-` in lieu of a variable name in a parameter (variable) expansion (`${...}`) makes escape sequences available that are normally used to represent environmental information in *prompt* strings, such as used in the `PS1` variable to determine the string displayed as the primary interactive prompt.

  - `%` is an instance of a parameter expansion flag, all of which are listed in `man zshexpn` under the heading `Parameter Expansion Flags`.
- `%x` is one of the escape sequences that can be used in prompt strings, and it functions as described above; there are many more, such as `%d` to represent the current dir.

  - `man zshmisc` lists all available sequences under the heading `SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES`.

Comment: Is there a documentation which other options apart form -%x are available?

Comment: I've seen `${(%):-%N}` used in other places, I just realized why `${(%):-%x}` is better: if you are inside a function, `%N` will return the name of the function, like `$0` with `FUNCTION_ARGZERO` does. `%x` returns the name of the script, like `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` does.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to make your script both bash and zsh-compatible you can use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]:-${(%):-%x}}`. The resulting value will be taken from `BASH_SOURCE[0]` when it's defined, and `${(%):-%x}}` when `BASH_SOURCE[0]` is not defined.

Answer (score 11):

`$0` is correct. In a sourced script, this is the name of a script, as it was passed to the `.` or `source` built-in (so if the `path_dirs` option is set, you may need to do a `$path` lookup to find the actual location of the script).

`.zshrc` is not sourced, which explains why `$0` is not set to `.zshrc`. You know the file name and location anyway: it's `${ZDOTDIR-~}/.zshrc`.

Comment: I'm still not sure this is correct. Create these two files: `foo` containing `source ./foo2` and `foo2` containing `echo $0`. Now run `./foo`, and you'll get the output of `./foo`, which is *not* the name of the sourced script. Replace `$0` with `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`, re-run with bash, and you'll get `./foo2`.

Comment: @Thanatos I get `./foo2` (zsh 4.3.10; this may have changed at some point, but not since 4.0). Compared with your instructions, I added `#!/bin/zsh` at the top of `foo`, to run the script under zsh. Are you sure you're running `foo` under zsh?

Comment: Just to clarify and emphasize... In **`zsh`** (and possibly other shells), the value of `$0` is the sourced script not the caller script. This is NOT how it works in Bash. So `$0` in zsh is the same as `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` in Bash.

Comment: Thanks toxalot, that's clear. But then - what is the portable way of doing this, in a shell script that should work in both bash and zsh then? No way?

Comment: @DavidFaure The portable way of doing what? Do you want to find the path to the master script, to the sourced script in which the current code is, or what?

Comment: The latter, since that's the subject of this whole post. But I found it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685135/how-to-get-parent-folder-of-executing-script-in-zsh : ${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}

Comment: @Gilles:  `.zshrc` _is_ sourced - as all initialization/profile files are by their very purpose. Aside from that, `zsh` _normally_ ALWAYS reports the _script_ path in `$0`, _irrespective of whether the script is being sourced or not_.
Apparently, the one exception are *initialization/profile files*, where zsh behaves like bash and ksh, setting `$0` to the *shell's* path (due to sourcing). (Thus, if anything, the fact that `$0` _doesn't_ reflect the *script* path in this case is another indicator that `.zshrc` _is_ being sourced.) The true zsh equivalent to `$BASH_SOURCE` is `${(%):-%x}`.

Comment: @toxalot: `$0` in `zsh` is the equivalent of `$BASH_SOURCE` in _most, but not all_ situations; the exceptions are: (a) in _initialization/profile files_ (e.g., `~/.zshrc`) `$0` inexplicably reports the *shell's* path, and (b) inside a _function_ it reports the _function's_ name. Again, the true equivalent is `${(%):-%x}`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are symlinking to .zshrc in a dotfiles directory and want to reference other files in the directory, then try this:

```
SOURCE=${(%):-%N}
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE"
done
DOTFILES_DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
```

(I got the loop script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in).)

Comment: Is there a documentation which other options apart form -%N are available?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for `$_`?

```
# foo.sh
source foo2.sh
```

and

```
# foo2.sh
echo $_
```

yields

```
# ./foo.sh
foo2.sh
```

Comment: for best result: `${BASH_SOURCE:-$_}`

Comment: It's best-practice to explain *why* an answer you provide works, or, in cases like this where the answer is <X feature>, to include a basic explanation of that feature. (hell, even copy-pasting a short section of the manpage is never a bad idea!)

Comment: $_ doesn't work in bash for the case where script1.sh sources script2.sh which then does echo $_. It will return script1.sh, i.e. $0 (the main script), while ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} return script2.sh (the subscript that is calling echo $_). So $_ is basically just like $0 AFAICS.

Comment: For anyone else wondering WTF `$_` is: "The _ variable is set to the absolute file name of your shell when you start it up (e.g. $_ = /bin/bash) or the script being executed if it's passed in an argument list when the shell is invoked. After that, it always expands to the value of the last command executed, or argument typed" (from http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/04/shell-special-variables-in-bash.html)

Answer (score 1):

Putting it all together for something that works in both bash and zsh:

```bash
SCRIPT_FILE_REL_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
if [[ "$SCRIPT_FILE_REL_PATH" == "" ]]; then
  SCRIPT_FILE_REL_PATH="${(%):-%N}"
fi
SCRIPT_FILE_PATH="`realpath $SCRIPT_FILE_REL_PATH`"
SCRIPT_DIR="`dirname $SCRIPT_FILE_PATH`"
```