# Tmux breaks zsh aliases

Tags: bash, shell, alias, zsh

I have a file .aliases that I point to in my .zshrc file

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
if [ -f $DIR"/.aliases" ]; then
    . $DIR"/.aliases"
fi
```

This code is the same in my .bashrc file (in the process of switching over to zsh). The aliases work fine when I open a new terminal - however when I change directory and open tmux, the aliases break. At first I thought this had something to do with whether the directory is the correct one - however, when I switch to bash, it works! So I am very confused as to what is causing this issue.

Comment: `BASH_SOURCE` is a `bash`-specific variable; it's not defined in `zsh`.

Comment: Why do you think it works when I start the shell? Wouldn't it fail then if that was an issue, not just in tmux/different directory? I guess unless it assigns it an empty string if it fails?

Comment: If the snippet you show is indeed in your `.zshrc` file, then `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` will expand to the empty string, because `BASH_SOURCE` will not have a value when `.zshrc` is sourced by `zsh`.

Comment: Ok, I found this old answer to fix it, seems to work now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901210/bash-source0-equivalent-in-zsh. Want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BASH_SOURCE` cannot be used in `.zshrc`, because it is a `bash`-specific variable that isn't defined in `zsh`. You'll have to replace it with its `zsh` equivalent, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901210/bash-source0-equivalent-in-zsh).