# zsh: get filename of the script that called a function

Tags: zsh, zshrc

Inside a function, how can I get the file name of whatever script called that function?

Via prompt expansion, `%x` provides the name of the file that defines the function. `%N` provides the function name. How do I get the name of the file that *called* the function?

This would be useful to report the runtime of each of my startup scripts, e.g.:

**`~/.zshenv:`**

```
function start_timer() {
  start_time=$(date +%s.%N)
}
function stop_timer() {
  stop_time=$(date +%s.%N)
  elapsed_time=$((stop_time-start_time))
  echo "$SCRIPTNAME took $elapsed_time seconds"
}
start_timer
# initialize env...
end_timer # "~/.zshenv took 0 seconds"
```

**`~/.zshrc:`**

```
start_timer
# initialize interactive shell...
end_timer # "~/.zshrc took 2 seconds"
```

**`~/.zlogin:`**

```
start_timer
# initialize login shell...
end_timer # "~/.zlogin took 2 seconds"
```

Comment: Here is a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901210) but also no real solution.

Answer (score 6):

At least in zsh 5.7.1, the `ZSH_ARGZERO` variable will report the name of the current script, even if the function within which it is called is different:

```
$ cat foo
function a_function_in_foo {
    echo "ZSH_ARGZERO=$ZSH_ARGZERO"
}
$ cat bar
source foo
a_function_in_foo
$ zsh bar
ZSH_ARGZERO=bar
```

It is documented at http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html as

> ZSH_ARGZERO
>
> If zsh was invoked to run a script, this is the name of the script. Otherwise, it is the name used to invoke the current shell. This is the same as the value of $0 when the POSIX_ARGZERO option is set, but is always available.

Comment: On zsh 5.8 with Debian: `$ZSH_ARGZERO` in a function echos `zsh` when script is called from a `terminal` and `~/.vscode/extensions/rogalmic.zsh-debug-0.1.3/zshdb_dir/zshdb` when run from `vscode` with `zsh-debug` extension.

Comment: @Timo Was the name of the script which you called from a terminal "zsh"? I'm not sure what the vscode zsh-debug extension does as I don't use vscode, but if it inserts itself into the zsh execution like most debuggers do, that seems like a reasonable output.

Answer (score 2):

`$0` doesn't work for sourced scripts. Try one of these options, which both work for me when added to my .zshrc*:

**Option 1**

Use `${(%):-%N}` or `${(%):-%x}` to get the path to the sourced script (either of these expansions worked for me).

```
sourcedFile=${(%):-%1N};
echo "${sourcedFile} took ${sec} second(s) to load.";
```

output:

> .zshrc took 2 second(s) to load.

**Option 2)**

Makes use `lsof +p $$` to get the name of the sourced script right when it is being sourced by `zsh`. Then, extract the line you need with something like `grep` and assign it to your variable. You can then use zsh expansion to extract the last "component" of the line:

```
sourcedFile=$(lsof +p $$ | grep zshrc);
echo "${sourcedFile:t0} took ${sec} second(s) to load.";
```

output:

> .zshrc took 2 second(s) to load.

*Option 2 obviously uses more cycles due to its use of `lsof`*

---

The expansion examples above are based on the zsh documentation. See `man zshexpn` > **HISTORY EXPANSION > Modifiers** and `man zshmisc` > **SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES** > **Shell state** for more detailed explanations.

Regarding Option 1, from `man zshmisc`:

> ```
>    %N     The name of the script, sourced file, or shell function that zsh is currently executing, whichever was
>           started most recently.  If there is none, this is equivalent to the parameter $0.  An integer may
>           follow the `%' to specify a number of trailing path components to show; zero means the full path.  A
>           negative integer specifies leading components.
> ```

For Option 1 above, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901210/bash-source0-equivalent-in-zsh) as my source for this solution.

* *Note: I'm currently on zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0) i.e. macOS 13.2.1, where I tested both options successfully.*

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the name as a parameter.

`~/.zshenv:`

```
function start_timer() {
  echo "File: `basename $@`"             # <----
  start_time=$(date +%s.%N)
}
```

`~/.zshrc:`

```
start_timer $0                           # <----
# initialize interactive shell...
end_timer # "~/.zshrc took 2 seconds"
```

*basename* only strips everything before the last slash in case you only want to show the file name.

My test:

```
 File: aliases.zsh
 took 0.0018649101257324219 seconds
```

And - if you call scripts by yourself you also can use `time` as a prefix command to print their execution times.

```
$ time touch x
touch x  0.00s user 0.00s system 7% cpu 0.019 total
```

Comment: When sourced on initialization by zsh, `$0` is simply `zsh` in every startup file. It would work if I passed the script name to the function directly, like `end_time ${(%):-%x}`, but you can see why I'd rather not use that at each invocation :)