# ZSH $ARG_ZERO not available

Tags: zsh

I am trying to use $ZSH_ARGZERO according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55214196/2000389) answer.

However that variable is not available in my terminal (interactive) or scripts. I assume a `setopt` has to be allowed (although I might be incorrect). I am not aware of having disabled it in my terminal.

my `zsh --version` is zsh 5.1.1.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ZSH_ARGZERO` was [introduced in Zsh 5.3](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/440c6beec09b3b4ba68955d807d48acef0d4360a). You will need to upgrade.