# Get the directory of an autoloaded function in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have an autoloaded function in my .zshrc, and I want to get its location dynamically so I can load another function in a nearby folder. But I can't figure out how to get the current folder of a function while it's being autoloaded or run.

```
# .zshrc:

fpath=(path/to/fn1 "$fpath[@]")
autoload -U fn1
```

```
# fn1

# ALL THREE OF THESE RESOLVE TO BE RELATIVE THE SHELL'S CURRENT DIRECTORY
pathToFn2="${0:P:h}/../path/to/fn2"
pathToFn2="${0:a:h}/../path/to/fn2"
pathToFn2="$PWD/../path/to/fn2"

fpath=($pathToFn2 "$fpath[@]")
autoload -U fn2

function fn1() {

  # OR I CAN LOAD IT INSIDE.
  # BUT I STILL GET PATHS RELATIVE TO THE SHELL'S CURRENT DIRECTORY
  pathToFn2="${0:P:h}/../path/to/fn2"
  pathToFn2="${0:a:h}/../path/to/fn2"
  pathToFn2="$PWD/../path/to/fn2"

  fpath=($pathToFn2 "$fpath[@]")
  autoload -U fn2

  fn2 blarg

}

fn1 "$@"
```

How do I get the current file name/directory either at function discovery or load/run time?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/23259585/707111?

Comment: @Ry thank  you, `${(%):-%x}` does what I need. Someone should write a better-organized modifier/flag reference for zsh. It's tricky to find stuff like this!